# SQL Optimization - Execute function only once for each distinct id in a Joined query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I am a full stack developer with only little knowledge about SQL.

Consider this code ->

(I have reduced my large query to this to pinpoint my doubt)

```
    SELECT get_lowest_due_date(f.fileId)
    FROM File f
    JOIN Order o 
     ON o.fileId =  f.fileId

    File

    fileId     fileName
    --------------------
    1            file1
    2            file2

    Order

    orderId     orderName      fileId
    ----------------------------------
    1            order1           1
    2            order2           1
    3            order3           2
```

I believe `get_lowest_due_date()` is being executed for all `fileId` values returned by the Join query (even duplicates).

Is there anyway that I can make the function execute only for unique values of `fileId`? I am trying to optimize the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT get_lowest_due_date(a.fileId)
FROM (SELECT f.fileId 
      FROM File f
      JOIN Order o 
      ON o.fileId =  f.fileId
      GROUP BY f.fileId) a
```

The inner query returns unique fileIds

Answer (score 1):

A SQL stored function (or stored procedure) can be DETERMINISTIC. That means your function's result depends only on its input value and not on other things. For example, `GETDATE()` is not deterministic, and `SQRT((x * x) + (y * y))` is.

When a function is DETERMINISTIC, the server optimizer avoids calling the function multiple times for the same values. If the function is not deterministic, the server optimizer generally does not have that freedom.

If your function contains SQL you may be wise to refactor your query into a JOIN or similar structure that puts the function's SQL directly into your query. That will allow the MySQL optimizer to incorporate its operations in the best possible way.

At any rate, your example calls your function for every value in `File.fileId`.  You could force it only to work with distinct values by using a nested query something like this.

```
 SELECT get_lowest_due_date(fileId)
   FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT f.fileId
             FROM File f
            JOIN Order o 
                 ON o.fileId =  f.fileId
        ) f
```

Answer (score 0):

A scalar functions gets called for each row returned by the select statement that it is being called from and yes scalar functions do not perform well.

You can convert this scalar function into an Inline-Table-Valued Function, (so the table returns a table instead of a scalar value), and use CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY to call the function.

**Function Definition:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_lowest_due_date (@fileId INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
  /* or whatever your logic is */
 SELECT Value from SomeTable WHERE fileId = @fileId
);
```

**Your new query:**

```
 SELECT *
    FROM File f
    JOIN Order o 
     ON o.fileId =  f.fileId
    CROSS APPLY  get_lowest_due_date(f.fileId)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the context of your question, you probably have other columns so returning just distinct file ids is not an option.

For your example, you can call the function in a subquery on `File`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (SELECT f.*, get_lowest_due_date(f.fileId) as lowest_due_date
      FROM File f
     ) f JOIN
     Order o 
     ON o.fileId =  f.fileId;
```

There are other tricks you can use, such as:

```
select fo.*,
       max(first_lowest_due_date) over (partition by fileid) as lowest_due_date
from (select . . .,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by fileid order by orderid) = 1
                   then get_lowest_due_date(f.fileId) 
              end) as first_lowest_due_date
      from file f join
           orders o
           on o.fileid = f.fileid
     ) fo;
```

That said, I suspect that you think that a user-defined function is a *good* idea.  SQL is not a programming language and -- alas -- user-defined functions pretty much have dismal performance.  If possible, I would suggest doing away with the function, perhaps using a view or a table-valued in-line function.